# problem while trying to install plugin with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install YouTube plugin as per instructions:

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/vibha/youtube-model.git
```

But I keep getting this error

```
svn: '/Users/tammam56/rubydev/war/vendor/plugins' is not a working copy
Plugin not found: ["git://github.com/vibha/youtube-model.git"]
```

I made sure I have git

```
which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

and making sure it's in path:

```
$PATH
-bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.1 and Mac OSX Leopard.

any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
script\plugin install http://github.com/vibha/youtube-model.git/
```

notice the "/" at the end!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you might also need to replace the line

stream.reopen(RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ ? 'NUL:' : '/dev/null')

with:

stream.reopen('NUL:')

in the file C:\Ruby19\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activesupport-2.3.5\lib\active_support\core_ext\kernel\reporting.rb